# How to convert Django TextField string into JSON?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField(default="[]")
```

Also, I have the following serializer:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
```

The REST API gets `data` and saves it as text field. In my `to_dict` method of `Car`, I want to convert `self.data` into JSON and return the dict:

```
def to_dict(self):
    result = dict()
    result['data']= json.loads(self.data)
    return result
```

But it fails with the error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

As I understand, the reason is that `self.data` is:

```
"['a', 'b', 'c']"
```

And not:

```
'["a", "b", "c"]'
```

I'm familiar with JsonField, but since I'm using SQLite without JSON1 externation, I can't use it. How can I convert `self.data` to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this problem is `json.loads(self.data.replace('\'','\"'))`.

Replace `'` to `"`.

Or you can try `eval(self.data)`

you can watch a sample [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_eval.asp) about the usage of `eval`

Comment: Yes of course but it feels like there could be a better solution. Also, what if one of the items contains `\'` or `"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) method to convert string into json format and then use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert json into python object.

```
import json

def to_dict(self):
    result = dict()
    data = json.dumps(self.data)
    result['data'] = json.loads(data)
    return result
```